# How to make an array of protected type?

Tags: vhdl

Having declared a protected type, and included body, like for example:

```
type flag_pt is protected
  procedure asg(val : boolean);
  impure function get return boolean;
end protected flag_pt;

type flag_pt is protected body
  ...
end protected body flag_pt;
```

How to make an array of `flag_pt`?

Trying the obvious:

```
type flag_array_pt is array (0 to 1) of flag_pt;
```

generates this error in ModelSim:

> An element of a protected type (flag_pt) is not allowed in a composite type.

Any suggestion for a workaround would also be appreciated; an obvious idea would be to build the array property into the `flag_pt`, but having to explicitly handle an index argument in all methods is pretty tedious, and become even worse for more complex data structures.

Comment: IEEE 1076-2008 states "Composite types are used to define collections of values. These include both arrays of values ... and records of values ... It is an error if a composite type contains elements of file types or protected types." So, Modelsim is correct to throw it out.

Comment: So, I thought I'd try an array of access types, but it turns out that "each such access value designates an object
of the subtype defined by the subtype indication of the access type definition. This subtype is called the
designated subtype and the base type of this subtype is called the designated type. The designated type shall
not be a file type or a protected type." (1076-1800 again)

Comment: Thanks, so it is correct that ModelSim makes an error.  Anyway, the code at least shows what I would like to achieve.  I tried to make an access type of a protected type, but ModelSim gives "Designated type of access type cannot be protected type", as expected based on your description.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor why not put it in an answer? So the question can be closed

Comment: The variable declared in the body of a protected type can be a composite type and your access methods can be passed an index.  This limits the number of simultaneous threads. Each calling process is guaranteed exclusive access, with one set of methods only one simultaneous access which is only a penalty when trying to use shared variables to communicate between processes in different design units on a multi-threaded simulation.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I don't have an answer. My comments merely clear up the fact that this is not a tool issue; what EquipDev is trying to do is illegal.

Comment: You can put both the array and its index in the protected type. We don't have enough of the picture to see whether the semantics will work well enough for your use case.

Comment: Hi Brian, Matthew and David, thanks for your feedback and suggestions; just wanted to be sure I did not overlook a language option for using protected types in a more flexible way.

Comment: The OSVVM package ScoreboardGenericPkg uses the method David suggests to implement arrays of scoreboards.   You can find OSVVM at github.